# Recorrer array asociativo de consulta mysql con php

Tags: php

Tengo este metodo en la clase cliente:

```html
public function Listar()
 {
  try
  {
            $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
   

   $stm=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM despensa.cliente;");
        $stm->execute();
           $array=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   return $array;
         
            
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
   die($e->getMessage());
  }
 }
```

Entonces antes de insertar quiero comprobar si ya existe el cliente por CUIT.

```html
public function comprueba($CUIT){
        $arrayexiste=self::Listar();
        

    foreach ($arrayexiste as $uno){
      
                
        if ($uno['CUIT']==$CUIT){
            return true;
            
        }else{ return false;}
    } }
```

Pero solo comprueba el primer registro, es decir no puedo insertar el mismo CUIT  del cliente 1, pero los demas se vuelven a insertar. Que esta mal?

haciendo vardump el array que devuelve listar() es:

**array(28) { [0]=> array(10) { ["idcliente"]=> string(3) "156" ["nombre"]=> string(14) "ANSWER WOLFRAM" ["CUIT"]=> string(11) "20224962070" ["deduda"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["iddescuento"]=> string(1) "1" ["telfijo"]=> string(0) "" ["celular"]=> string(0) "" ["direccion"]=> string(61) "2000 MTS. AL ESTE ESCUELA 7 COLONIA VILLA LIBERTAD ENTRE RIOS" ["condicionIVA"]=> string(1) "1" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [1]=> array(10) { ["idcliente"]=> string(3) "159" ["nombre"]=> string(2) "dd" ["CUIT"]=> string(0) "" ["deduda"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["iddescuento"]=> string(1) "1" ["telfijo"]=> string(0) "" ["celular"]=> string(0) "" ["direccion"]=> string(0) "" ["condicionIVA"]=> string(1) "1" ["activo"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(10) { ["idcliente"]=> string(3) "160" ["nombre"]=> string(23) "PATRICIA LAURA KRISTIAN" ["CUIT"]=> string(11) "20084199312" ["deduda"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["iddescuento"]=> string(1) "1" ["telfijo"]=> string(0) "" ["celular"]=> string(0) "" ["direccion"]=> string(33) "CASEROS 528 FEDERACION ENTRE RIOS" ["condicionIVA"]=> string(1) "2" **

Añado la implementacion de la funcion comprueba:

```html
 public function registrar($nombre,$CUIT,$deuda,$iddescuento,$telfijo,$celular,$direccion,$cIVA,$activo)
 {
    if (self::comprueba($CUIT)==true){
    echo "CUIT ya existente en la base de datos";
 }else{
  try 
  {

    
             $conexion=Conexion::singleton_conexion();
            $conexion->beginTransaction();  
  $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (idcliente,nombre,CUIT,deduda,iddescuento,telfijo,celular,direccion,condicionIVA,activo)"; 
  $sql.=" VALUES (null,'".$nombre."','".$CUIT."',".$deuda.",".$iddescuento.",'".$telfijo."','".$celular."','".$direccion."',".$cIVA.",".$activo.");";

       $conexion->query($sql);
       $conexion->commit();
       echo "Alta exitosa";
            
        
    
       
  } catch (Exception $e) 
  {
   die($e->getMessage());
            $conexion->rollBack();
  }
 }}
```

En ese metodo intento insertar un cliente y no quiero insertar el mismo.

Comment: en el foreach puedes probar que, en lugar de retrornar true o false ir creando dos arrays uno con los que si se pueden insertar y otro con los que no, posteriormente guardas los del primero

Comment: Es para no duplicar una misma persona registrada dos veces..si esta una vez no lo inserto y listo

Comment: pues la solución que te propongo debería hacerlo también, como no veo como estas y cuando estas ejecutando ese filtro, puedes enviar todo el array de todas als persoans que vas a registrar y en el foreach donde pregutnas si existe, crear el array con la gente que no existe y que si vas a registrar.

Comment: Osea el insert es de una sola persona. Es un formulario de alta de cliente. Quiero verificar que no se inserte dos veces el mismo cuit o nombre si se quisiera.

Comment: Agregue el metodo que usa la funcion comprueba...

Comment: `fetchAll` devuelve los datos anidados, para leerlos tienes que hacer algo como esto si mal no recuerdo: `foreach ($arrayexiste as $rows){ foreach ($rows as $uno) {  // resto del código } }`  si no funciona así, prueba de este modo: `foreach ($arrayexiste[0] as $uno){ //resto del código }` antes de intentar la inserción directamente, prueba a ver si los datos se muestran correctamente.

Comment: La funcion que lista los clientes tiene un FETCH_ASSOC no fetchAll, probe pero sigue evaluando el primer registro..osea no itera

Comment: Si hago if ($array[5]['CUIT']==$CUIT){ por ejemplo y pruebo con el CUIT del quinto cliente funciona perfecto, me detecta que ya existe. Pero sino usa el primero. Osea si hago   for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){
             
            if ($array[5]['CUIT']==$CUIT){
                return true;
            }else{return false;}
        } }  no funciona

Comment: Ya encontre la respuesta. el problema es que no lleva el return false, porque sino se sale del proceso, osea dentro del if retorna true, de lo contrario sigue iterando.